# Wordpress Adding button link

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, button

I've got the following code and the normal `href` is not working to add a link to the button. Any ideas?

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
[
 service pattern = "boxpattern-1"
 bgcolor         = "#ffffff"
 icon            = "http://www.aquaflowright.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cogwheel.png"
 title           = "Services"
 button          = "Learn More"
]Surveys, Testing, Installation, Repair, Maintenance, Notices, and Revenue Assurance[/service]</p>
```

Comment: This is a shortcode, not a button. Maybe a shortcode that returns a button. You have to look into the source code off this shortcode to know his attributes. Or maybe there is a doc for?

Comment: Check the theme or plugin, which adds the shortcode. And paste the callback function here. Then we can check.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in the code, use do_shortcode():

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[service pattern="boxpattern-1" bgcolor="#ffffff" icon="http://www.aquaflowright.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cogwheel.png" title="Services" button="Learn More" ]'); ?>
```